# Debian Squeeze Ganeti - lvm.conf filter problem

Tags: virtualization, xen, lvm, ganeti

I've been integrating the ganeti project and it has a problem with the ":" character at the PV ( physical volume ), name.
By adding the line `filter = [ "r|:|", "a|.*|"]` in **/etc/lvm.conf**, when creating PV, it is written correct. But when create a VG on it, it's displayed again with the incorect way like : `/dev/block/104:17`

```
root@node2:~# pvdisplay
  "/dev/cciss/c0d1p1" is a new physical volume of "33.91 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/cciss/c0d1p1
  VG Name
  PV Size               33.91 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               piPcN8-SwXe-gd57-sXFf-KSvF-tk0p-OXias7
```

When create VG ( vgcreate xenvg /dev/cciss/c0d1p1 ), the output is becoming : /dev/block/104:17 which is not functional output for the application that I've been using ( ganeti ).

```
root@node2:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/block/104:17
  VG Name               xenvg
  PV Size               33.91 GiB / not usable 3.80 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              8681
  Free PE               8681
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               piPcN8-SwXe-gd57-sXFf-KSvF-tk0p-OXias7
```

P.S
It's only added the ( filter = [ "r|:|", "a|.*|"] ), in lvm.conf, without ( preferred_names ) line.  Where is my mistake, please to explain.

Complete story:
http://code.google.com/p/ganeti/issues/detail?id=93

Kind regards
Vladimir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of reading in documentations, I've managed to solve the problem. 
The key was :

> preferred_names = [ "^/dev/dm-*/" ,
>   "^/dev/cciss/" ]

```
root@mainframe1:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/cciss/c0d1p1
  VG Name               xenvg
  PV Size               33.91 GiB / not usable 3.80 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              8681
  Free PE               8681
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               wtjoOE-dGpv-xoVK-pKa1-Bra4-dvRr-PSoO7o
```

As you the output **/dev/block/104:17** has disapeared.

In summary the was adding these lines in **/etc/lvm/lvm.conf** :

```
preferred_names = [ "^/dev/dm-*/" , "^/dev/cciss/" ]

filter = [ "r|:|", "a|.*|"]
```

Kind regards
Vladimir